# Solving $2x^3-24x^2+23x+283=0$

Tags: complex-numbers, cubics

I need to solve this equation:

$$\frac{x^2+1}{x-4}+\frac{x^2-1}{x+3}=23$$

When opened up it comes to this:

$$2x^3-24x^2+23x+283=0$$

Then I am stuck...

It feels like it has something to do with complex numbers perhaps?

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: This does not have trivial roots, so you are up for Cardan's formulas.

Comment: @JohnDoe: not quite: it should be $-24x^2$.

Comment: @JohnDoe I am clueless of Cardano's formulas, just checking. Do you happen to see the steps in wolfram alpha? That would be amazing..

Comment: @thuban, no sorry, I don't know how to solve these equations either

Comment: @thuban: Wikipedia's [Cubic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation) entry walks-through solution strategies.

Comment: @Blue thank you..

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Kahan's method**, see [Help finding x in cubic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3360581/help-finding-x-in-cubic-function/3361178#3361178)

For your example, let $f(x) = Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D = 2x^3-24x^2+23x+283$

$k = -{B\over3A} = {24\over6} = 4$

$f(k)/A = 119/2$

$f'(k)/A = -73/2 < 0$

$guess = k - (1.324718)(1)max(\sqrt[3]{119/2}, \sqrt{73/2}) = -4.00331$

**Newton's method**:
$-4.00331 → -2.96890 → -2.74377 → -2.73328 → -2.73326 → x = -2.73325591833$

---

$|x^3| ≈ 20.4193 < |D/A| = 283/2$ → deflate cubics using synthetic division

$E=Ax+B=-29.4665118367$
$F=Ex+C=103.53951787$

For quadratics, $Ax^2+Ex+F=0$, go for the "big" root, to reduce errors.

$\large x_1 = -{E\;+\;sign(E) \sqrt{E^2-4AF} \over 2A} = \normalsize 8.94695974511$
$\large x_2 = {F/A\over x_1} = \normalsize 5.78629617322$

$$f(x)\;roots = -2.73325591833, 5.78629617322,8.94695974511$$

Comment: Thank you so much. Would you please clarify which way did you use to find the roots of the final second level equation? Thanks!

Comment: I added the quadratic solving steps.  Is this what you meant by final second level equation ?

Comment: Absolutely! Thank you so much that's crystal clear now

Comment: Note: if |x^3| > |D/A|, it is more accurate to deflate cubic in reverse.  For an example, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3361178/696342

Comment: Added Cardano's method example here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3376107/696342

Answer (score 2):

Let me be more puristic.

The first thing to notice is that the discriminant is positive $(\Delta=1582748)$; so three real roots with $p=-\frac{73}{2}$ and $q=\frac{119}{2}$.

Now, instead of Cardano, let us use the trigonometric method for cubic equation which write
$$x_k=-\frac b{3a}+2\sqrt{-\frac p 3} \cos\Big(\frac 13 \cos^{-1}\Big(\frac{3q}{2p}\sqrt{-\frac 3p } \Big)-\frac{2\pi}3k\Big)\qquad \text{for}\qquad k=0,1,2$$
Applied to your case this will give
$$x_k=4+\sqrt{\frac{146}{3}} \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  k}{3}-\frac{1}{3} \cos
   ^{-1}\left(-\frac{357}{73}\sqrt{\frac{3}{146}}\right)\right)$$

Their decimal representation would be
$$x_0=8.94695974511457058 \qquad x_1=5.78629617321812462\qquad x_2=-2.73325591833269521$$

**Edit**

If you use your pocket calculator
$$\frac{1}{3} \cos
   ^{-1}\left(-\frac{357}{73}\sqrt{\frac{3}{146}}\right)\approx 0.782540 \qquad \text{while} \qquad \frac \pi 4\approx 0.785398$$ and $$\sqrt{\frac{146}{3}}\approx 6.97615$$ So, as an *approximation*,
$$x_k \sim 4+7 \cos \left(\frac{8 k-3}{12} \pi  \right)$$ which would give
$$x_1=4+\frac{7}{\sqrt{2}} \approx 8.94975 \quad x_2=4+\frac{7 \left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)}{2 \sqrt{2}}\approx 5.81173\quad x_3=4-\frac{7 \left(\sqrt{3}+1\right)}{2 \sqrt{2}}\approx -2.76148$$

Answer (score 1):

Numerical methods result in three real solutions. 
Here are decimal approximations to the roots.

$$-2.733256, 5.7862962,8.9469597$$

Comment: How did you solve it? Cardano's? Any steps you can share?

Comment: @thuban Newton's Method is a fast way to find the zeros. $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac {f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$